# how to print values in array of deferred objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have the following requests:

```
var req1 = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                dataType : "xml"
            });

            req1.done(function (resp1) {
                $(resp1).find('interest').each(function() {

                    var interest_id = $(this).find('id').text();
                    var interest_name = $(this).find('name').text();

                    var request = $.ajax({
                        type:"GET",
                        url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page="+ interest_name + "&redirects&prop=text",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    });

                    requestsArray.push(request);

                 });

                $.when.apply(null, requestsArray).done(function () {
                    console.log("entrou");

                });

            });
```

But when i get inside of

```
$.when.apply(null, requestsArray).done(function () {
                        console.log("entrou");

                    });
```

I dont know how to reach the individual responses in requestsArray. how can i do that? i have tried and tried but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `arguments` object to access an unknown number of values passed to a function:

```
$.when.apply($, requestsArray).done(function(){
  console.log(arguments); //plain arguments object
  console.log([].slice.call(arguments)); //arguments turned into real array
});
```

See [MDN docs on the arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Since you are pushing `$.ajax`s into your array you might consider getting rid of the additional arguments they will pass like:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page="+ interest_name + "&redirects&prop=text",
    dataType: "jsonp"
}).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    return data; //this will make sure textStatus and jqXHR aren't passed any further
});
```

Comment: [] would be my array requestsArray?

Comment: but like that i wont have all the requests done when i execute then

Comment: @João, no this is just the shortest way to transform the arguments object into a real array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like - your `requestsArray` would just be `requestsArray`

Comment: @João what makes you think so?

Comment: @João The two blocks of code go together. The second one is just preventing the additional data (`textStatus`, `jqXHR`) to appear in your `arguments`.